# Make a 3D geographics with boundary of province

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, curated-data, geography

This is a example in documentation of `GeoElevationData`(Neat Examples).

```
latlon = Transpose[
    GeoBounds[Entity["Country", "China"]]] + {{-35, -5}, {15, 15}};
elevation = Reverse[QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData[latlon]]];
ListPlot3D[elevation, 
 AspectRatio -> (Divide @@ Dimensions[elevation]), Boxed -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Background -> Black, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["HypsometricTints"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

I have to say such map is very useful for a history lover.But I have some dissatisfaction still.

1. It show the mountain perfectly,but we cannot get any information about **river**.There is a example in `ref / GeoStyling / Scope / "ReliefMap"`

   [image]

   We can see the river very exactly.Any solution can improve above map?
2. We cannot distinguish the boundary of province. As we know, the boundary like following:

   ```
   GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], 
     Polygon /@ {Entity["Country", "Taiwan"], 
       Sequence @@ 
        EntityList[
         Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
             "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
            Entity["Country", "China"]}]]}}, GeoBackground -> None]
   ```

   [image]

Can anyone improve it?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can use whatever `GeoGraphics` as a `Texture` if you set appropriate `GeoRange`.

Your example with administrative bounds doesn't work so I just put there China border.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the way to highlight rivers. E.g. `Entity["River", "Yangtze"]["Properties"]` does not contain anything relevant to plot.

```
latlon = Transpose[
    GeoBounds[Entity["Country", "China"]]
] + {{-35, -5}, {15, 15}};

elevation = Reverse[QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData[latlon]]];

plot = GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm@Thick, Polygon@Entity["Country", "China"]}, 
  GeoRange -> latlon, 
  GeoZoomLevel -> 5,  
  ImageSize -> 3000
];

ListPlot3D[   elevation,
 Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Background -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture@plot, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .3}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,but the `GeoZoomLevel ` can include the *Yangtze River*

Comment: @yode yep, yet it won't be highlighted in any special way you can use with GeoGraphics primitives.

Comment: Maybe the larger value of `GeoZoomLevel` will get that river information.But my network too weak.As you answer.we can distinguish administrative bounds,you can get it by run `Values[Databin["fVDlquaN"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Some behavior have changed in 11.2, then the code in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126842/make-a-3d-geographics-with-boundary-of-province#comment343501_126951) is work almost

```
size = 2000;
latlon = Transpose[
   GeoBounds[Entity["Country", "China"]]] + {{-35, -5}, {15, 
    15}}; elevation = 
 Reverse[QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData[latlon]]]; plot = 
 GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[], 
   Polygon /@ 
    Append[EntityList[
      Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
          "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
         Entity["Country", "China"]}]], Entity["Country", "Taiwan"]]},
   GeoRange -> latlon, GeoZoomLevel -> 6, ImageSize -> size];
ListPlot3D[elevation, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
 Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Texture[plot], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.3}, Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> size]
```

[image]